# KeywordQuery and Taxonomy fields

Tags: search, taxonomy, keywordquery

I'm programatically trying to use the Search Apis to find some documents.

In order to customize the process, I'm selecting some basic properties :

```
var query = new KeywordQuery(site)
{
    QueryText = queryText,
    ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults
};

query.SelectProperties.Add("Title");
query.SelectProperties.Add("Language");

...

var result = query.Execute();
```

This is working fine.

Now I want to select the internal values of a taxonomy field. Let's say I have a field named `AccessLevel`, bound to a term set containing some values.

After a crawl, SharePoint has detected two crawled properties : `AccessLevel` (property containing the label) and `ows_taxId_AccessLevel` (property containing the lookup value of the taxonomy field, `#label|termguid`). A mapped property has also been created `owstaxIdAccessLevel` automatically.

I **set up the crawled properties to be included in the index**, I even start the full crawl, but if I add this code :

```
query.SelectProperties.Add("owstaxIdAccessLevel");
```

I got the following exception :

```
Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.InvalidPropertyException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings.
  Source=Microsoft.Office.Server.Search
  Property=The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.ThrowBackwardCompatibleException(FaultException`1 ex)
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName)
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoWebServiceBackedOperation[T](String operationName, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall)
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties)
       at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.Execute()
       atMyProject.MyModuleConnectorSearchWrapper.SearchDocuments(SPSite site, String queryText, IEnumerable`1 retrieveProperties, Boolean includeDefaultProperties, Int32 startRow, Int32 rowsPerPage, Int32& estimatedRowCount)
       atMyProject.WebService.MyModuleConnector.<>c__DisplayClass3.<Search>b__1()
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2()
       at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
  InnerException: System.ServiceModel.FaultException<Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationFault>
       Message=The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason.
       Source=mscorlib
       Action=http://tempuri.org/ISearchQueryServiceApplication/ExecuteSearchServiceApplicationFaultFault
       StackTrace:
         Server stack trace: 
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
         Exception rethrown at [0]: 
            at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
            at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
            at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.ISearchQueryServiceApplication.Execute(QueryProperties properties)
            at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Execute>b__3(ISearchServiceApplication serviceApplication)
            at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32 wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName)
       InnerException:
```

Is there any restriction on querying Taxonomy fields? What can I do to make my search works?

Comment: I haven't found out exactly why this is, but I have done it successfully on one system, the same deployment on another produces your error. I read if you map it to the other field (The plaintext version of the field) of the managed metadata field it works. Didn't fix it for me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting discovery... if I run this small PS script:

```
$prop = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication $ssa -Identity owstaxIdAccessLevel
$prop.Retrievable
```

It's returning:

> False

Then I can update this property:

```
$prop.Retrievable = $true
$prop.Update()
```

After a full crawl, I'm now able to query my taxonomy field.

However, I'm don't measure now the potential side effects of this change

Comment: there are no side effects. the automatically created managed property for TaxonomyFields is NOT Retrievable by Default. And if it is not retrievable, you cannot request it. That´s all.